# Не могу найти логи, которые писались в папку без прав

Tags: linux, логирование

У меня есть приложение email-service которое развернута на сервере с linux.  Около месяца приложение не писало логи в нужную папку, которая была прописана в настройках приложения. Сейчас мы выяснили что приложению не хватало прав и после того как мы дали приложению права логи стали записываться в нужную папку.

Мне нужны файлы с логами, которые не записывались в нужную папку всё это время. С помощью `journalctl` я могу их посмотреть. Значит где то данная информация должна лежать. И сейчас мне нужно узнать где именно.

Я также искал в `/var/log/`, но не нашел нужные файлы.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Из документации к `journald-systemd`:

```
/run/log/journal/machine-id/*.journal, /run/log/journal/machine-id/*.journal~,
/var/log/journal/machine-id/*.journal, /var/log/journal/machine-id/*.journal~
           systemd-journald writes entries to files in /run/log/journal/machine-id/ or
           /var/log/journal/machine-id/ with the ".journal" suffix. If the daemon is stopped uncleanly, or if
           the files are found to be corrupted, they are renamed using the ".journal~" suffix, and
           systemd-journald starts writing to a new file.  /run is used when /var/log/journal is not
           available, or when Storage=volatile is set in the journald.conf(5) configuration file.
```

Но вы кстати можете использовать `journalctl` для получения логов нужного сервиса и отправить вывод в файл.